# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar los segundos y deshabilitar los minutos y segundos en un input TIME?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Se tiene un input del tipo `time` sencillo como el siguiente ejemplo:

```
<input type="time" id="hora" step="1"/>
```

Me gustaria saber si es posible deshabilitar los minutos y los segundos, que estén siempre en 00:00, que solamente sea posible cambiar la hora. ¿Es posible, con javascript o jquery?

Dejo un ejemplo de aquello:

```js
function AumentaHoras(){
  
  document.getElementById('hora').stepUp(3600);

}
```

```css
#hora{
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-color: black;
 border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<input type="time" id="hora" step="1" value="00:00:00">

<button onclick="AumentaHoras()">Click me!</button>
```

Probando de esta manera, se logra que aumente de hora en hora, pero no deshabilita los minutos y los segundos.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function AuementaHoras(){
    document.getElementById('hora').stepUp(3600);
  }
<script>
```

Además al llegar a las 23:59:59 Hrs, si se sigue aumentando no se restablece a 00:00:00, y los minutos y segundos toman valores cuando deberían estar siempre en 00:00.

Pero si lo hago de este modo se cumple todo, excepto que no muestra los segundos, tampoco con javascript, en su propiedad `.value="";`

```
<input type="time" id="hora" step="3600"/>
```

Comment: si quieres un selector de horas por qué usar un input time?

Comment: Según he estado leyendo el **input** no soporta lo que necesitas que haga. Efectivamente con **step** puedes conseguir que los incrementos y decrementos de tiempo sean de una hora, pero entonces no te va a mostrar los segundos porque el navegador no lo ve necesario. Si necesitas que el input te muestre los segundos ya tendrías que jugar con un **input text**, añadiéndole tú unos botoncitos para que hagan de controles incrementales y decrementales y ser tú quien maneje el string resultante para simular el efecto que deseas conseguir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He logrado lo que deseas con el siguiente fragmento de código, espero que te sirva, sino comentame si tienes alguna dificultad, saludos:

```js
        function AumentaHoras(){
          hora = document.getElementById('hora').value;
          if ( hora == undefined || hora != "23:00:00" ) {
            document.getElementById('hora').stepUp(3600);
          }else{
            document.getElementById('hora').value = "00:00:00";
          }
        }
```

```html
      <input type="time" id="hora" step="1"/>

      <button onclick="AumentaHoras()">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Amigo funciona muy bien aquello sólo que lo modifiqué un poco; además **sigue permitiendo modificar los minutos y segundos;** mi idea es utilizar los controles del input time para controlar las horas a la vez que se muestran los segundos. Si es posible.